# how can I get to know which server side programming is used by the website?

Tags: web

I like to which server side programming is used by website
Like if I visit any web-site then how can i get to know that which server side programming is used by the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each server side programming language has their own quarks which make them distinct. w3af has a number of "Discovery" plugins for gaining information about a remote server.  A good example is the w3af plugin [PHPEggs](http://w3af.sourceforge.net/plugin-descriptions.php#phpEggs).

> ```
>   This plugin tries to find the documented easter eggs that exist in PHP and identify
>     the remote PHP version using the easter egg content. The easter eggs that this plugin
>     verifies are:
> ```

```
        - http://php.net/?=PHPB8B5F2A0-3C92-11d3-A3A9-4C7B08C10000 ( PHP Credits )
        - http://php.net/?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 ( PHP Logo )
        - http://php.net/?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 ( Zend Logo )
        - http://php.net/?=PHPE9568F36-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 ( PHP Logo 2 )
```

Answer (score 4):

It is may possible via some methods:

- Just look at the file extension (`.php` is obviously generated by php)
- Examine the HTML for a software which was used create that and google for it
- Search on-site for the software used
- Examine the HTTP-Header
- Just try to google it (this should at least work for major sites)

If none of these will help, there is no chance of finding it out except emailing the company.

Comment: Note that none of the above is guaranteed.  It is trivial to change mimic extensions for other languages which i scommon when replacing the site and keeping search engine indexes in place.  Further http headers etc are also trivially changed and sometimes this is done to send hackers on a wild goose chase.

Comment: But it might give a clue on the language used, of course that's not gueranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can get hints from observing the HTTP headers and page "extensions" e.g. asp.

... but you can never be sure e.g. masquerading page extensions is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the page extension, for example .php

If the website uses mod_rewrite you can't see wich language they use.

Comment: they don't even need mod_rewrite; merely changing the scripthandler should work.